# Total hour in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database field that has a value such as. 1140250673 this is the "time spent on a solution" When I use

`To_Char (To_Timestamp (workorder. timespentonreq/1000), 'HH 24 ')`

I see only the records with the value of the max 24 hours. What should I use to have a sum of hours or for 1140250673 = 316hrs 44min

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear, but I think you're looking for the interval type:

```
# select justify_interval(1140250673 / 1000 * '1 second'::interval);
 justify_interval 
------------------
 13 days 04:44:10
(1 row)
```

Comment: I get an error when using justify_interval :( I read that I can also use the cast function, just do not know how:(

Comment: `justify_interval()` expects an interval, hence the `* '1 second'::interval` bit.

Comment: I found a similar question and I know how to pull out the hour and minute. Now I just have to connect it in one column.